# How to create a Text file and save it to a shared-directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, network-programming

I'm having an issue here, I developed an application in C# which creates a text file. This text file is saved in the X:\Public\3rd\ASN\, the problem is that in development the files are created and saved with no issues but once I move the application into our Web Server the appplication fails and it throws out this error "Could not find a part of the path X:\Public\3rd\ASN\1175_0001.txt".

This is the code I'm using to saved the file in the directory:

```
w = File.CreateText("X:\Public\Public\3rd\ASN\1175ASN_0001.txt");
```

Keep in mind that this directory is another server.

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Comment: You cannot use drive letters in the web application as the drive letters are associated with the logged in user. The web applications should use UNC paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your X drive is a mapped network drive.  You need to use the network url eg `\\server\directory\Public\3rd\ASN\1175_0001.txt`

Comment: You don't use Server.MapPath with UNCs.

Comment: you don't need to map the network drive on the server.  just go into your computer and find out what the X drive is mapped to and use that directory, instead of X: